# Python: saving image from web to disk

Tags: python

Can I save images to disk using python? An example of an image would be:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest is to use [`urllib.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve).

Python 2:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('http://chart.apis.google.com/...', 'outfile.png')
```

Python 3:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://chart.apis.google.com/...', 'outfile.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to download a png to disk, you can do so with [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html):

```
import urllib
urladdy = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=1:|0|10|100|1%2C000|10%2C000|100%2C000|1%2C000%2C000|2:||Excretion+in+Nanograms+per+gram+creatinine+milliliter+(logarithmic+scale)|&chxp=1,0|2,0&chxr=0,0,12.1|1,0,3&chxs=0,676767,13.5,0,lt,676767|1,676767,13.5,0,l,676767&chxtc=0,-1000&chxt=y,x,x&chbh=a,1,0&chs=640x465&cht=bvs&chco=A2C180&chds=0,12.1&chd=t:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,3,2,4,6,6,9,3,6,5,11,9,10,6,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0&chdl=n=87&chtt=William+MD+-+Buprenorphine+Graph"
filename = r"c:\tmp\toto\file.png"
urllib.urlretrieve(urladdy, filename)
```

In python 3, you will need to use `urllib.request.urlretrieve` instead of `urllib.urlretrieve`.

Answer (score 0):

The Google chart API produces PNG files. Just retrieve them with `urllib.urlopen(url).read()` or something along these lines and safe to a file the usual way.

Full example:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> url = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=1:|0|10|100|1%2C000|10%2C000|100%2C000|1%2C000%2C000|2:||Excretion+in+Nanograms+per+gram+creatinine+milliliter+(logarithmic+scale)|&chxp=1,0|2,0&chxr=0,0,12.1|1,0,3&chxs=0,676767,13.5,0,lt,676767|1,676767,13.5,0,l,676767&chxtc=0,-1000&chxt=y,x,x&chbh=a,1,0&chs=640x465&cht=bvs&chco=A2C180&chds=0,12.1&chd=t:0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,3,2,4,6,6,9,3,6,5,11,9,10,6,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0&chdl=n=87&chtt=William+MD+-+Buprenorphine+Graph'
>>> image = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
>>> outfile = open('chart01.png','wb')
>>> outfile.write(image)
>>> outfile.close()
```

As noted in other examples, 'urllib.urlretrieve(url, outfilename)` is even more straightforward, but playing with urllib and urllib2 will surely be instructive for you.